# R, web scraping, rvest, transfermarkt data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape transfermarkt data for private purposes (no commercial use).

In particular, I need information about all transfers for a given time period. It is possible to search for transfers by day, my plan is to search for each day using this page: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/plus/0?land_id_ab=&land_id_zu=&leihe=&datum=2000-07-02

I need the table at the bottom of this page.

I'm using `rvest` to do it. Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/plus/0?land_id_ab=&land_id_zu=&leihe=&datum=2000-07-02"
site =  read_html(url)
site %>% html_node("#yw1 td") %>% html_table() %>% View()
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

This code worked about a year ago, but not now. I've tried to add `html_session`, but the result is the same.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

404 is the http error saying you can't access this page.

If you try this url in your browser (as I did), you'll notice you can't access this url — this is why you can't scrape it.

More on internet http error : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

You can programmatically check for error with `httr` :

```
GET(url) %>% status_code()
```

Colin

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can access this page using my browser (Chrome).

Comment: I got an error when I wrote the answer. This is indeed working now. 
It's possible for a website to install methods to prevent web scraping. This may be the case here. 

If you try in your terminal, you'll get : 

colin@colin-MacBookPro:~$ curl http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/plus/0?land_id_ab=&land_id_zu=&leihe=&datum=2000-07-02
colin@colin-MacBookPro:~$ <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

@Petr

I get a different error than you when I run your code.  Instead of the 404 error I get "Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE"

I was able to set the variable `site` properly.

I was also able to use `tbls <- html_nodes(site, "table")` to get a list of all tables on the page.

Then using `html_table(tbls[6])` I was able to see the last table on the html page of

```
  X1            X2
1 NA José Bosingwa
2 NA    Right-Back
```

Is this what you are looking for?  Can you run each of these commands in sequence?  If not, where does it fall apart on you?

Comment: That's strange. I have an error while setting site variable: site =  read_html(url)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
But in brower I can open this page.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, have you updated your `rvest` package?

Comment: Yes, but the result is still the same :(

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out?  I am really curious why the same code would work for me and not for you.

Comment: No, I'm trying to do it with RSelenium.